# negative power of number inside parenthesize

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My algebra textbook and calculator says

$$(-3)^0=1 \quad \& \quad -3^0=-1$$

Why does the paranthesis make a difference on the negative/positive of the result?

Comment: This is just order of operations $ma^b$ means $m\times (a^b)$, not $(ma)^b$.

Comment: $(-3)^0 = (-1)^0*3^0 = 1*1$

Comment: Because $(-a)^n $ means you are taking $-a $ to the n power.  But $-a^n=-(a^n) $ means you are taking $a $ to the n power and negating it.  Different things.  $(-3)^2=(-3)*(-3)=9$ but $-3^2=-3*3=-9$.

Answer (score 2):

When parentheses are present, it's clear how to do things; but with parentheses missing, there can be multiple interpretations, and we have to pick one by convention.

---

Let's say you want to evaluate the expression "$4-3+1$". There are two reasonable things you could do:

- First do "$4-3$," which gives $1$; then add $1$, giving $2$. That is, read the problem as $$(4-3)+1.$$
- First do $3+1$, giving $4$, and then subtract that from $4$, giving $0$. That is, read the problem as $$4-(3+1).$$

Although [sometimes parentheses aren't needed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property), in general they are.

This is exactly what's going on here! The expression "$-3^0$" could be interpreted as:

- $(-3)^0$

or

- $-(3^0)$.

If we had parentheses, we'd know which it was easily.

In lieu of parentheses, we just fix some convention of which operations to do first - that is, what our [**order of operations**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) is. There isn't necessarily a good argument for what we choose here, we just need to choose *something* and stick with it.

As it happens, the convention is that exponentiation binds more tightly than multiplication ($-3$ is just $(-1)\cdot 3$), so we read "$-3^0$" as "$-(3^0)$." But the convention could have gone the other way.